# How can I find out what is causing "This webpage is not available" in IIS 8?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, iis-8

We have an internal web application running in IIS 8 / Windows Server 2012.  Our users are sporadically reporting seeing "This webpage is not available" on a very regular basis.  Reloading in their browser of choice will generally cause the page to be loaded successfully, but this is still frustrating people.

Generally I would expect the server to be overwhelmed, but I've been watching resource monitor on the server for some time and I'm not seeing any unusual load.  This is a Dell PowerEdge R720XD with 24GB of RAM and 2x Quad Core Xeons running at 1.8 GHz.  It is only supporting a user load of about 40 individuals.

Where should I look to find out exactly what is causing this?  I had very little luck with Google, and am more of a developer that a server administrator.  Is there some logging I can set up that will shed some light?  There are TONS of options in performance monitor.  Should I be tracking some specific metrics there?

Comment: As a first step have one (or more) users turn off friendly HTTP messages in their browser settings so that you can get more detailed info from the browser when the page doesn't load.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with the symptoms you're describing, you need to troubleshoot the code, not the server environment. Assuming your server is healthy of course - and if you're not seeing anything in event viewer and performance monitor, it probably is.

From the front end, put some load-testing together and see if you can find a commonality on failures. From the backend, start putting in some logging/tracing.

Answer (score 0):

First I would try to find out whether this is a server, client or network problem.

If you have a specific time when one of this problems occurred, you could check the IIS http logs and look for any non-2xx or 3xx entries.

If there is nothing in the server logs, you could capture the network traffic on the client. In IE you can use the F12 tools, they allow you to save the capture, so a user could send them to you. You could also use Fiddler or a more low-level network monitor software.